# Python `nx.maximum_flow_value`

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, networkx, connectivity, edges

I'm using the following code sample in Python to calculate the flow between every pair of nodes in the graph below to identify whether the graph is 2 connected. It returns that the graph is 2 connected and all pairs of nodes have flow `>=2`, which is false because the marked area has a cut node. I can't identify what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me with that?

```
for edge in list(T.edges()):
    T[edge[0]][edge[1]]['capacity']=1
    T[edge[1]][edge[0]]['capacity']=1

flow3 =[]

for d in V: 
    tempvert =[]
    tempvert = set(V) - set([d])    
    for a in tempvert:
        flow_value = nx.maximum_flow_value(T, a, d,capacity = '1')
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the cut node has two edges in and out of it.  The capacity you've defined is on the edges.  So because it has 2 edges from each region,  this node has enough capacity to carry 2 units of whatever between the two regions.

Comment: @Joel Thank you very much for your feedback! Is there a way that I . could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `nx.node_connectivity(G)`.  Here is the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.connectivity.node_connectivity.html#networkx.algorithms.connectivity.connectivity.node_connectivity).